# rake db:reset does not populated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Environment -> Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails v3.0.5

I noted a strange pattern in rake db:reset. According to rails source code, rake db:reset will => db:drop, db:create and db:migrate. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.5/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L159

**Setup:** One of my migration files have Model.create statements to populate some data (Forgive me, I'm not the one who had put data-filling-code in those migrations :) ..)

**Case 1:** When I do the steps manually, i mean drop, create, and migrate, one by one - those statements fill data in the table.

**Case 2:** When I do just rake db:reset, schema is set properly. but the data is not entering the db. Does db:reset skip create/update statements.. I have tried this several times to make sure that I have no faults in the steps I do. I still get this behavior.

what is going wrong here... ?

Comment: can you post your migrations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're reading the wrong line in the source. As I read it:

`db:migrate:reset` # => `[:drop, :create, :migrate]`

`db:reset` # => `[:drop, :setup]`

So `db:reset` just create the tables and sets the migrations as if they had been run, without actually running them. `db:migrate:reset` actually runs each migration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before but I was running 3.0.3, and it turns out, somehow I manage to mess up the migrations by change the migrations files and not running the migrations(forgot about it or something)...I'll start by checking those files